# How to get app store country code in React Native

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

we have a react-native app with in-app purchases both available on the iOS and Google stores. We would like a way to determine the current country the user is in before triggering the purchase flow, in order to correctly display the respective pricing schemes in advance.

We have contemplated using device locale, phone number country codes, and other fingerprinting techniques to deduce this, but would like a more definitive solution.

We are also using this package, which has a country option, but it doesn't meet our production needs:

### [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this somehow?

Comment: @Tyrannogina unfortunately not yet

Comment: did you manage to solve?

Comment: @JojoNarte nope but it’s been a while, wouldn’t be surprised is someone has a solution now. Lemme know if you find one

Comment: No great solution out there as of yet. All open source code I found are not maintained and old !!!

Comment: @JojoNarte found a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### InAppUtils

Finally found a working solution to this using the following package:

https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils

```
const identifiers = [
   'com.xyz.abc',
];

InAppUtils.loadProducts(identifiers, (error, products) => {
   console.log(products);
   //update store here.
});
```

Loading products will give you the amount, currency type, and country code, etc.